# Granting permission to domain user not working

Tags: vbscript, icacls

I'm converting my code to use `icacls` and currently following this tutorial: https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html.

On this part,

> Grant the user jdoe rights to create, edit and delete files in the
>   folder C:\demo\example\, but prevent deletion of the folder itself:
>
> :: First remove inheritance and grant admins Full control to the top
>   folder icacls "C:\demo\example" /inheritance:r /grant:r
>   administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
>
> :: Grant Modify + Delete Child to subfolders and files only icacls
>   "C:\demo\example" /grant:r ss64Dom\jdoe:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M,DC) /T
>
> :: Grant Read/Execute, Write and Append to the top level folder icacls
>   "C:\demo\example" /grant:r ss64Dom\jdoe:(RX,WD,AD)
>
> :: if any pre-existing subfolders Grant admins Full control icacls
>   "C:\demo\example" /grant:r administrators:(OI)(CI)(F) /T

, I was able to get the right results for the first instruction but the second one doesn't work for me. I tried to change the `M,DC` part with `F` but it doesn't work as well.

This is my code.

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Dim objShell,objFSO, ProgramFiles, X, Y, intRunError, strFolders,strFiles, strNTGroup
Dim strFolder, strFile, strUserName, strEveryone, strDomain

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strFolders = Array(_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder3",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder2",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_folder")

strFiles = Array(_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_file.txt",_
"C:\Users\User\Documents\test_file2.txt")

'User's User Name
strDomain = "Domain"
strUserName = strDomain & "\User"
strEveryone = "Everyone"

WScript.Echo "Set permissions for", strUserName, vbCRLF

'Assign User Permissions to Folders.
For X = 0 to Ubound(strFolders)
    strFolder = strFolders(X)
    If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolder) Then
        WScript.Echo "Folder: " & strFolder
        'intRunError = objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c Echo Y| cacls " & strFolder & " /E /C /G " & strUserName & ":F", 2, True)
        objShell.Run "icacls " & strFolder & " /inheritance:r /grant:r administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)", 2, True
        intRunError = objShell.Run("icacls " & strFolder & " /grant:r " & strUserName & ":(OI)(CI)(IO)(M,DC) /T", 2, True)

        If intRunError <> 0 Then
            Wscript.Echo "Folder ErrCode: " & intRunError
            Wscript.Echo "Error assigning permissions for user " _
            & strNTGroup & " to folder " & strFolder
        End If

    Else
        WScript.Echo "Folder " & strFolder & " not found"
    End If
Next
```

I'm running it on my local Windows 7 PC btw.

UPDATE:

From [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eecebc05-80bd-4d24-abc0-7e4f01e8ce4a/icacls-systax-for-recursively-adding-permissions-for-administrators-to-a-folder-without-altering?forum=winservergen), I found about

> Subfolders and files only (OI)(CI)(NP)(IO)

which is the same as what the 2nd instruction wants to do so I tried to use it.
It doesn't do anything at first but after a few, about 6 times, compilation with and without `(NP)`, the user account gets a full permission even when I didn't change the permissions on the code is still `(M,DC)`.

Currently, my folder structure is like this.

```
test_folder
|- test_test_file
|- test_test_folder
    |- test_test_test_folder
    |- test_test_test_file
```

On test_folder, Administrator and User both have full permission. It's subfolder have Administrator and User but both doesn't have any permission checked in it.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with VBScript. You are obfuscating your commands.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm fairly new to using `vbscript`. Please explain the parts that I've done incorrectly. And I just copied it from the website so I guess their commands are also wrong.

Comment: All you are doing is running user commands so vbscript is irrelevant. Ask on https://superuser.com.

Comment: But that's what I was asked to use. I already file a new question on superuser.com. https://superuser.com/questions/1443691/granting-permission-to-domain-user-not-working

Comment: And maybe https://serverfault.com may be a better place.

Comment: Yeah, I keep finding some stuff there as well. But is it ok to post multiple copies of a question on different forums?

Comment: @Noodles this is my question on serverfault, if you might be interested. https://serverfault.com/questions/971202/logon-script-applied-but-not-running